# How to reapply changes from a previously completed pull request?

Tags: git

Recently sent in a PR that was reviewed and accepted, which resulted in an unforeseen bug. My lead dev reverted the master branch back to what it was before the pr. I got to work fixing the errors, however he did not revert the PR, he just reverted the repo. So when I went to make a new pr with all the changes from my feature branch, the new PR only contained the changes I made since the first PR, i.e. none of the original changes. How can I get *all* of the changes from my feature branch into the master, i.e. the cumulative changes of both PR's.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your local branch has all of your changes, you may only need to rebase from the current `master`

Answer (score 0):

> So when I went to make a new pr with all the changes from my feature branch, the new PR only contained the changes I made since the first PR

Correct. That is what happens when you revert a merge commit. The revert undoes the *effect* of the merge on the main branch, but the merge is still there and the topology is unchanged, so Git sees that all the earlier commits are already present in that topology and does not let you add them again.

See, always see, the definitive document on this situation, https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt.

As you've been told, the solution is to rebase your feature branch onto the end of the main branch. Now you have commits that behave just like the commits of your original feature branch, but they are *different* commits (copies). Thus when you make a pull request to merge into the main branch, you see all of the commits.